# Testing the CAPM: does GRS account for errors in variables (measurement error)?

Tags: asset-pricing, capm, estimation

Suppose we are interested in testing the CAPM using the [GRS test](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1913625). Consider $N$ assets observed for $T$ time periods. Using the notation of Cochrane ["Asset Pricing"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691121376/asset-pricing) (2005), the GRS test amounts to running $N$ time series regressions of the form
$$
R^{ei}_t=\alpha_i+\beta_i f_t+\varepsilon^i_t \tag{12.1}
$$
and testing the joint hypothesis $H_0\colon \alpha_1=\dots=\alpha_N=0$. The $\alpha$s are treated as pricing errors, so they better be zero if the CAPM is an adequate model.

However, I have a quibble with using $(12.1)$ for testing the CAPM. Consider the following. The CAPM states that
$$
E(R^{ei})=\beta_i E(f).
$$
While it is a single-period model, let us assume it works in all $T$ periods so that $E(R^{ei}_t)=\beta_i E(f_t)$ where $E(f_t)\equiv E(f)=:\lambda$. Let us further assume the relevant covariances and variances and thus $\beta$s are constant over time, too. This implies
$$
R^{ei}_t = \tilde\alpha_i+\tilde\beta_i \lambda+\varepsilon^i_t. \tag{12.1'}
$$
with $\tilde\alpha_1=\dots=\tilde\alpha_N=0$.

Comparing $(12.1)$ to $(12.1')$, we see that the former replaces $\lambda$ with $f_t$ thus introducing a measurement error (a.k.a. errors in variables). Therefore, the OLS point estimates $\hat\alpha^{\text{12.1 by OLS}}_i$ and $\hat\beta^{\text{12.1 by OLS}}_i$ are not even consistent$\color{red}{^*}$ for the true values $\tilde\alpha_i$ and $\tilde\beta_i$ corresponding to $(12.1')$.

**Question:** Does the GRS test take care of $\lambda$ being replaced by $f_t$?

$\color{red}{^*}$I have now realized the statement about consistency may be wrong, since we have a rather special case of $\lambda$ being a constant rather than a variable. I will check and come back to this later...

*Due to lack of answers, a version of this question has been reposted on [Cross Validated Stack Exchange.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605427)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Matthew Gunn's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605427/understanding-the-grs-test-of-the-capital-asset-pricing-model/605542#605542) to the linked thread on Cross Validated. It turns out that $\alpha_i\neq 0$ in $(12.1)$ **does** imply the CAPM cannot hold. To see that, take the expectations of both sides of $(12.1)$ under $\alpha_i\neq 0$. Therefore, a test of $H_0\colon \alpha_1=\dots=\alpha_N=0$ is a valid test of the CAPM.